# regular expression non greedy matching

Tags: regex, non-greedy

I need a regular expression that matches the shortest string between "$" and  "|$"

Example test string:

```
'bla bla$bla bla $bla bla|$bla bla bla'
```

regular expression:

```
/\$(.*?)\|\$/
```

i get

```
'bla bla $bla bla'
```

but i need 
bla bla

Has anyone an idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negated character class:

```
\$([^$]*)\|\$
```

Comment: It is not correct, as it won't match strings like `bla$ bla | bla |$ bla`. Just remove the `|` from square brackets.